# Python Typing: Mypy complains about dictionary of generic callable accepting and returning any subclass

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, callable

Mypy is complaining about the Callables I am storing in this dictionary. The Callables accept a sublclass of `BinLogEvent` and return a subclass of `BaseEventSchema` (a pydantic model). I have used the same bound TypeVars for similar situations successfully elsewhere in the code. I'm not sure what the issue is here. I have tried:

1. Using both actual base classes, both type vars, and the combinations thereof
2. Using capital "D" Typing.Dict instead of dict.

Python 3.10, mypy 0.971

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

```
EventSchema = TypeVar("EventSchema", bound=BaseEventSchema) # Base class for all event schemas
LogEvent = TypeVar("LogEvent", bound=BinLogEvent) # Base class for all events

def _serialize_rows_event(event: RowsEvent) -> RowEventSchema:
     ...

def _serialize_query_event(event: QueryEvent) -> QueryEventSchema:
     ...

# Mypy complains about both entries 
# Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "str": "Callable[[RowsEvent], RowEventSchema]";
# expected "str": "Callable[[LogEvent], EventSchema]"
_serializer_mapping: dict[str, Callable[[LogEvent], EventSchema]] = {
    RowsEvent.__name__: _serialize_rows_event, 
    QueryEvent.__name__: _serialize_query_event,
}

# No errors for this function which uses the dictionary
def serialize_event(event: LogEvent) -> EventSchema:
    handler = _serializer_mapping[_get_type_str(event)]
    return handler(event)
```

Comment: First of all, you cannot use type variables in this context, they are unbound.

Comment: You're facing variance issue here. One of the possible solutions could be [like this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=497ec0b4941b571f0d5d44af059a71de).